# Solution: load independently compiled Webpack 2 bundles dynamically

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to share how to bundle an application that acts as a **plugin host** and how it can load installed plugins **dynamically**.

1. Both the application and the plugins are bundled with Webpack
2. The application and plugins are compiled and distributed *independently*.

There are several people on the net who are looking for a solution to this problem:

- [Multi-project build and dynamically loading modules with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502035/multi-project-build-and-dynamically-loading-modules-with-webpack)
- [Loading prebuilt webpack bundles at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780950/loading-prebuilt-webpack-bundles-at-runtime)
- [How to expose objects from Webpack bundle and inject external libs into compiled bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035445/how-to-expose-objects-from-webpack-bundle-and-inject-external-libs-into-compiled-bundle)
- Dynamic Requires
  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118

The solution described here is based on @sokra's Apr 17, 2014 comment on Webpack issue #118 and is slightly adapted in order to work with Webpack 2.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118

Main points:

- A plugin needs an ID (or "URI") by which it registers at the backend server, and which is unique to the application.
- In order to avoid chunk/module ID collisions for every plugin, individual `JSONP` loader functions will be used for loading the plugin's chunks.
- Loading a plugin is initiated by dynamically created `<script>` elements (instead of `require()`) and let the main application eventually consume the plugin's exports through a `JSONP` callback.

Note: You may find Webpack's "JSONP" wording misleading as actually no `JSON` is transferred but the plugin's Javascript wrapped in a "loader function". No padding takes place at server-side.

**Building a plugin**

A plugin's build configuration uses Webpack's `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget` options.

Example plugin configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/' + pluginUri + '/',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    library: pluginIdent,
    libraryTarget: 'jsonp'
  },
  ...
}
```

It's up to the plugin developer to choose an unique ID (or "URI") for the plugin and make it available in the plugin configuration. Here I use the variable `pluginURI`:

```
// unique plugin ID (using dots for namespacing)
var pluginUri = 'com.companyX.pluginY'
```

For the `library` option you also have to specify an unique name for the plugin. Webpack will use this name when generating the `JSONP` loader functions. I derive the function name from the plugin URI:

```
// transform plugin URI into a valid function name
var pluginIdent = "_" + pluginUri.replace(/\./g, '_')
```

Note that when the `library` option is set Webpack derives a value for the `output.jsonpFunction` option automatically.

When building the plugin Webpack generates 3 distribution files:

```
dist/js/manifest.js
dist/js/vendor.js
dist/js/main.js
```

Note that `vendor.js` and `main.js` are wrapped in JSONP loader functions whose names are taken from `output.jsonpFunction` and `output.library` respectively.

Your backend server must serve the distribution files of each installed plugin. For example, my backend server serves the content of a plugin's `dist/` directory under the plugin's URI as the 1st path component:

```
/com.companyX.pluginY/js/manifest.js
/com.companyX.pluginY/js/vendor.js
/com.companyX.pluginY/js/main.js
```

That's why `publicPath` is set to `'/' + pluginUri + '/'` in the example plugin config.

Note: The distribution files can be served as static resources. The backend server is not required to do any padding (the "P" in `JSONP`). The distribution files are "padded" by Webpack already at build time.

**Loading plugins**

The main application is supposed to retrieve the list of the installed plugin (URI)s from the backend server.

```
// retrieved from server
var pluginUris = [
  'com.companyX.pluginX',
  'com.companyX.pluginY',
  'org.organizationX.pluginX',
]
```

Then load the plugins:

```
loadPlugins () {
  pluginUris.forEach(pluginUri => loadPlugin(pluginUri, function (exports) {
    // the exports of the plugin's main file are available in `exports`
  }))
}
```

Now the application has access to the plugin's exports. At this point, the original problem of loading an independently compiled plugin is basically solved :-)

A plugin is loaded by loading its 3 chunks (`manifest.js`, `vendor.js`, `main.js`) in sequence. Once main.js is loaded the callback will be invoked.

```
function loadPlugin (pluginUri, mainCallback) {
  installMainCallback(pluginUri, mainCallback)
  loadPluginChunk(pluginUri, 'manifest', () =>
    loadPluginChunk(pluginUri, 'vendor', () =>
      loadPluginChunk(pluginUri, 'main')
    )
  )
}
```

Callback invocation works by defining a global function whose name equals `output.library` as in the plugin config. The application derives that name from the `pluginUri` (just like we did in the plugin config already).

```
function installMainCallback (pluginUri, mainCallback) {
  var _pluginIdent = pluginIdent(pluginUri)
  window[_pluginIdent] = function (exports) {
    delete window[_pluginIdent]
    mainCallback(exports)
  }
}
```

A chunk is loaded by dynamically creating a `<script>` element:

```
function loadPluginChunk (pluginUri, name, callback) {
  return loadScript(pluginChunk(pluginUri, name), callback)
}

function loadScript (url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = url
  script.onload = function () {
    document.head.removeChild(script)
    callback && callback()
  }
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}
```

Helper:

```
function pluginIdent (pluginUri) {
  return '_' + pluginUri.replace(/\./g, '_')
}

function pluginChunk (pluginUri, name) {
  return '/' + pluginUri + '/js/' + name + '.js'
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could make a repo which demoes this concept?

Comment: At the moment I can't make a repo, sorry. Let me know which part you have problems with. I'll improve the article then.

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing this! I have just one question: is there any way to inject dependencies from the original webpack bundle? I want to load react components dynamically and without adding it to the bundle that is loaded dynamically.

Comment: @AlexanderF A plugin could export a constructor function which expects the needed dependencies as arguments, e.g. the `React` object. When the main application loads the plugins it would call each plugin's constructor function and pass the dependencies. The plugin would not import `react` (and in the plugin's `package.json` would be no `react` dependency). So react would not be bundled with the plugin. The React object is injected via the constructor function.

Comment: @JörgRichter Thanks a lot, this is a pretty straightforward solution to the problem.

Comment: @JörgRichter: Did this work for you? For me, it does not work. I get an error saying that packJsonpplugin is not defined. When I make sure that this function is put into the lazy loaded bundle, I cannot access things from the origin bundle.

Comment: @JörgRichter When building with that output config I only get `main.js`, is that normal? Also, how would you test serving these bundles locally?

Comment: Can we split bundle module wise during webpack build?

Comment: @Trent `manifest.js` and `vendor.js` are generated by the `CommonsChunkPlugin` (in order to split app and vendor code). It's config is not shown in the article. Without that config you only get `main.js`. That's normal. Sorry for the confusion. For serving you can use any Webserver.

Comment: @Trent After installing the callback just load `main.js`. That works for me.

Comment: Is there a question buried in here someplace? While interesting, this is a Q&A site. This post should be removed and hosted on a more appropriate forum for discussion.

Comment: To expand on what @ScotMatson wrote ("This post should be removed and hosted on a more appropriate forum for discussion."): Either that or split into a question part and the answer portion provided in an answer.

Comment: @JörgRichter can you please explain when and where do you load the plugins and how do you access to your imported modules?

Comment: @Kangcor Your frontend loads the plugins as part of its startup procedure. See my frontend's `loadPluginsFromServer()` function:
https://github.com/jri/deepamehta/blob/master/modules/dm4-webclient/src/main/js/plugin-manager.js#L66
While plugin initialization the frontend could inject global dependencies (e.g. React) via plugin constructor function. See @AlexanderF's question and my answer above.
Let me know if you need more detailed information.

Comment: @Kangcor For a demo plugin repo see https://github.com/jri/dm5-plugin-template The plugin main file (the Webpack entry point) is `src/main/js/plugin.js`. Whatever you export from there is available in the plugin loader's main callback (See section "Loading plugins"). Your plugin can export anything relevant to your frontend, e.g. a (constructor) function for dependency injection. See also `webpack.config.js`. Note: *frontend* and *main application* are used synonymously here. The plugin loader is part of your frontend.

Comment: The approach described in the article works also with Webpack 3 and Webpack 4.

Comment: this seems to be useful content but is not in the proper format for this site. It should probably be posted as an answer to [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035445/how-to-expose-objects-from-webpack-bundle-and-inject-external-libs-into-compiled), instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs as answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035445/how-to-expose-objects-from-webpack-bundle-and-inject-external-libs-into-compiled), it's not a standalone question.