# Loading precompiled bundles at runtime in a JS application

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, fusebox, parceljs

Currently, I have a React application built with Webpack 1.15.0.

I want to load into my application one or more precompiled bundles at runtime, like in a plugin system. The main application doesn't know the names of these bundles, but it knows that they will be in a specific directory.

I found this solution: 
[Solution: load independently compiled Webpack 2 bundles dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163909/solution-load-independently-compiled-webpack-2-bundles-dynamically)
but it seems a bit complex.

Can I accomplish this in a simpler way by using Webpack, Fusebox, Parcel or any other tool?

Comment: FuseBox can load any javascript or json files dynamically using the import statement. As long as this file contains module.exports it's gonna be imported as a regular module.

Comment: Have you heard about lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: @MatheusSilva
As far as I know, lazy-loaded modules should be known at compile time. I need to provide module at runtime. The main app doesn't know them at compile time

Comment: @user3677173
Does FuseBox load external compiled modules or does it compile external modules on the fly? Please, can you provide an example or a link to some documentation?

Comment: https://fuse-box.org/page/dynamic-import It provides exports to the module. Therefore you would need to have these module transpiled down to es5. However, you could hook up an additional pre-processor on that

Comment: Thanks @user3677173. This seems going towards an acceptable solution. However, since I have bundled ES5 JavaScript, how can I export it as a commonjs module?
In other words, there is a way to dynamically import compiled bundles that are not commonjs modules?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of [nchanged](https://github.com/nchanged) I reached a solution to my issue based on Fusebox.

I created [a simple POC on GitHub](https://github.com/andychiare/fuseboxTest) to show how to configure two projects to allow dynamic loading of a pre-compiled bundle.

I hope this can be useful for someone else.